# About javascript and DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I want to use DOM to change the page background color and div background color, and I think I can use getElementById and onclick. So I write code to achieve. But it not work.

What's wrong with my code?

How to fix it?

HTML

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <mate charset="utf-8" />
    <title>change color</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="test">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="bodyColor">change body background-color</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="divColor">change div background-color</a>
    </div>
<script src="test.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body *{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

a{
    display: block;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 150px auto;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#test{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

javascript

```
function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      oldonload();
      func();
    }
  }
}

function bodyBackgroundColor(){
    var color = document.getElementById('bodyColor');
    color.onclick = function(){
        body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}

function divBackgroundColor(){
    var color = document.getElementById('divColor');
    var divColor = document.getElementById('test');
    color.onclick = function(){
        divColor.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}

addLoadEvent(bodyBackgroundColor);
addLoadEvent(divBackgroundColor);
```

Comment: You can add defer attribute to your script tag, so that you will not have to add onLoadEvent, your script will execute after DOM will load.

Comment: move <script src="test.js"> </script> right before </body>

Comment: Check your console for errors? Something like `body is not defined` maybe?

Comment: @Beri: Or just put the script at the end, which is more broadly-supported.

Comment: why don't you use on Click in anchor tag?

Comment: @SohailHameed I think structural layer, presentation layer, layer behavior should be completely separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bodyBackgroundColor`, you need `document.` before `body` (`body` is not a global):

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

In `divBackgroundColor`, you've left out `.style.`:

```
divColor.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

---

And rather than the complicated `addLoadEvent`, just move your `script` tag to the end of the page, just before the closing `</body>` tag. Then all of the elements defined above it will exist and you can interact with them. More in the [YUI Best Practices for Speeding Up your Website](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html).

---

To debug these kinds of things, with any modern browser you can use the built-in debugger. Press F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I or find "Dev Tools" on the browser's menu, and you'll find that you can see the source code of your page, set breakpoints in it (places where the JavaScript engine stops and lets you see what's going on before it continues); you can single-step through code (watch it execute one line at a time), inspect variables, etc.

The most basic part of the debugger is the console, which shows you errors (amongst other things).

Comment: I do as you say, the problem is solved. Thank you very much! And I think I ignored to the console.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved finally.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <mate charset="utf-8" />
    <title>change color</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />

</head>

<body>
    <div id="test">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="bodyColor">change body background-color</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="divColor">change div background-color</a>
    </div>
    <script src="test.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
    body *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a{
    display: block;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 150px auto;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#test{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

javascript

```
  function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      oldonload();
      func();
    }
  }
}

function bodyBackgroundColor(){
    var color = document.getElementById('bodyColor');
    //var bodyforthis = document.getElementsByTagName('body')
    color.onclick = function(){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}

function divBackgroundColor(){
    var color = document.getElementById('divColor');
    var divColor = document.getElementById('test');
    color.onclick = function(){
        divColor.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }
}

addLoadEvent(bodyBackgroundColor);
addLoadEvent(divBackgroundColor);
```

**Or use a simpler method**

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <mate charset="utf-8" />
    <title>change color</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />

</head>

<body>
    <div id="test">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="bodyColor">change body background-color</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="divColor">change div background-color</a>
    </div>
    <script>
    function bodyBackgroundColor(){
        var color = document.getElementById('bodyColor');
    //var bodyforthis = document.getElementsByTagName('body')
        color.onclick = function(){
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            }
    }

    function divBackgroundColor(){
        var color = document.getElementById('divColor');
        var divColor = document.getElementById('test');
        color.onclick = function(){
            divColor.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        }
    }
    window.onload = bodyBackgroundColor();
    window.onload = divBackgroundColor();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a{
    display: block;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 150px auto;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#test{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```